# Parsing nested JSON errors

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON file I am trying to extract data from and I keep getting errors that I cannot resolve for some reason, any advice?

Here is how I am running it in playgrounds

```
import UIKit

struct GETprojects: Codable {
    var projectGetResult: Bool
    var projectGetProjects: ProjectGetProjects
}

struct ProjectGetProjects: Codable {
    var projects: [Projects] = Array()
}

struct Projects: Codable {
    var id: String
    var name:  String
    var status:  String
    var category:  String
    var type:  String
    var updated:  String
    var value:  String
    var units:  String
    var address:  Address
    var contacts: Contacts
}

struct Address: Codable {
    var  erf: String
    var  street: String
    var  street2: String
    var  town: String
    var  city: String
    var  region: String
    var  postalCode: String
}

struct Contacts: Codable {
    var professional, contractor: Contact
}

struct Contact: Codable {
   var  id: String
    var  name: String
    var  company: String
    var  phone: String
    var  mobile: String
    var  email: String
    var  type: String
}
'''

let JSONString = """
{
    "projectGetResult": true,
    "projectGetProjects": [
      {
          "id": "123-uni-que",
          "name": "Amazon",
          "status": "Planning",
          "category": "Commercial",
          "type": "Office Block",
          "updated": "21 March 2023",
          "value": 100000000,
          "units": 1,
          "address": {
              "erf": "101-RE",
              "street": "First Avenue",
              "street2": "",
              "town": "Cape Town",
              "city": "Cape Town",
              "region": "Western Cape",
              "postalCode": "111"
          },
          "contacts": {
              "professional": [
                  {
                  "id": "pr123",
                  "name":"Charles Darwin",
                  "company":"Darwin Designs",
                  "phone":"011 234 5678",
                  "mobile":"071 234 5678",
                  "email":"darwin@archi.com",
                  "type":"Architect"
                  },
                  {
                  "id": "pr234",
                  "name":"Bill Hutchins",
                  "company":"Hutchins Engineering",
                  "phone":"012 345 6789",
                  "mobile":"072 345 6789",
                  "email":"bill@engi.com",
                  "type":"Engineer"
                  },
    {
    "id": "pr345",
    "name":"Kevin Counter",
    "company":"KCQS",
    "phone":"013 456 7890",
    "mobile":"073 456 7890",
    "email":"k@county.com",
    "type":"Quantity Surveyor"
    }
    ],
    "contractor": [
    {
    "id": "con123",
    "name":"Leonardo da Vinci",
    "company":"MegaBuild",
    "phone":"014 567 8901",
    "mobile":"074 567 8901",
    "email":"leo@buildy.com",
    "type":"Main"
    },
    {
    "id": "con234",
    "name":"Steve Cleer",
                  "company":"SC Civils",
                  "phone":"015 678 9012",
                  "mobile":"075 678 9012",
                  "email":"sc@earthy.com",
                  "type":"Civil"
                  },
                  {
                      "id": "con345",
                      "name":"Warren Fright",
                      "company":"Electrified",
                      "phone":"016 789 0123",
                      "mobile":"076 789 0123",
                      "email":"@sparky.com",
                      "type":"Electrical"
                      }
              ]
          }
      },
      {
          "id": "234-uni-que",
          "name": "TBC SA",
          "status": "On Site",
          "category": "Commercial",
          "type": "Office Block",
          "updated": "21 March 2023",
          "value": 200000000,
          "units": 2,
          "address": {
              "erf": "102-RE",
              "street": "Second Avenue",
              "street2": "Corner of 4th",
              "town": "Stellenbosch",
              "city": "Cape Town",
              "region": "Western Cape",
              "postalCode": "222"
          },
          "contacts":  {
                  "professional": [
                      {
                      "id": "pr123",
                      "name":"Charles Darwin",
                      "company":"Darwin Designs",
                      "phone":"011 234 5678",
                      "mobile":"071 234 5678",
                      "email":"darwin@archi.com",
                      "type":"Architect"
                      },
                      {
                      "id": "pr234",
                      "name":"Bill Hutchins",
                      "company":"Hutchins Engineering",
                      "phone":"012 345 6789",
                      "mobile":"072 345 6789",
                      "email":"bill@engi.com",
                      "type":"Engineer"
                      },
                      {
                          "id": "pr345",
                          "name":"Kevin Counter",
                          "company":"KCQS",
                          "phone":"013 456 7890",
                          "mobile":"073 456 7890",
                          "email":"k@county.com",
                          "type":"Quantity Surveyor"
                          }
                  ],
                  "contractor": [
                      {
                      "id": "con123",
                      "name":"Leonardo da Vinci",
                      "company":"MegaBuild",
                      "phone":"014 567 8901",
                      "mobile":"074 567 8901",
                      "email":"leo@buildy.com",
                      "type":"Main"
                      },
                      {
                      "id": "con234",
                      "name":"Steve Cleer",
                      "company":"SC Civils",
                      "phone":"015 678 9012",
                      "mobile":"075 678 9012",
                      "email":"sc@earthy.com",
                      "type":"Civil"
                      },
                      {
                          "id": "con345",
                          "name":"Warren Fright",
                          "company":"Electrified",
                          "phone":"016 789 0123",
                          "mobile":"076 789 0123",
                          "email":"@sparky.com",
                          "type":"Electrical"
                          }
                  ]
              }
      },
      {
          "id": "345-uni-que",
          "name": "Rolling Stock",
          "status": "Out to Tender",
          "category": "Commercial",
          "type": "Office Block",
          "updated": "21 March 2023",
          "value": 300000000,
          "units": 3,
          "address": {
              "erf": "103-RE",
              "street": "Third Avenue",
              "street2": "",
              "town": "Swellendam",
              "city": "Drakenstein",
              "region": "Western Cape",
              "postalCode": "333"
          },
          "contacts":  {
                  "professional": [
                      {
                      "id": "pr123",
                      "name":"Charles Darwin",
                      "company":"Darwin Designs",
                      "phone":"011 234 5678",
                      "mobile":"071 234 5678",
                      "email":"darwin@archi.com",
                      "type":"Architect"
                      },
                      {
                      "id": "pr234",
                      "name":"Bill Hutchins",
                      "company":"Hutchins Engineering",
                      "phone":"012 345 6789",
                      "mobile":"072 345 6789",
                      "email":"bill@engi.com",
                      "type":"Engineer"
                      },
    {
    "id": "pr345",
    "name":"Kevin Counter",
    "company":"KCQS",
    "phone":"013 456 7890",
    "mobile":"073 456 7890",
    "email":"k@county.com",
    "type":"Quantity Surveyor"
    }
    ],
    "contractor": [
    {
    "id": "con123",
    "name":"Leonardo da Vinci",
    "company":"MegaBuild",
    "phone":"014 567 8901",
    "mobile":"074 567 8901",
    "email":"leo@buildy.com",
    "type":"Main"
    },
    {
    "id": "con234",
    "name":"Steve Cleer",
    "company":"SC Civils",
    "phone":"015 678 9012",
    "mobile":"075 678 9012",
    "email":"sc@earthy.com",
    "type":"Civil"
    },
    {
    "id": "con345",
    "name":"Warren Fright",
    "company":"Electrified",
    "phone":"016 789 0123",
    "mobile":"076 789 0123",
    "email":"@sparky.com",
    "type":"Electrical"
    }
    ]
    }}]}
"""
```

```
print(JSONString)
let jsonData = JSONString.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  let tableData = try decoder.decode(GETprojects.self, from: jsonData)
  print(tableData)
    print("Rows in array: \(tableData.projectGetProjects.count)")
}
catch {
  print (error)
}`
```

getting the error:

```
**Value of type 'GETprojects' has no member 'GETprojects'**
at: print("Rows in array: \(tableData.GETprojects.projectGetProjects.count)")
```

No matter how I configure the tableData I get a similar error, what am I missing?

Comment: `tableData.projectGetProjects.projects.count`?

Comment: No luck with this unfortunately, same error just with regards to .projects.count

Comment: `projectGetProjects` at the top level object is clearly an array, note the `[]` in the JSON. There are only 2 (two!) collection types in JSON, array `[]` and dictionary `{}`. And there is no key `projects` in the JSON. And who has created such cumbersome key names? Why not just `result` and `projects`? And `Projects` is supposed to be named in singular form `Project`, **one** instance is **one** project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you've created the wrong model.
Try this model and follow this website to create a model. https://app.quicktype.io/

```
// MARK: - GETprojects
struct GETprojects: Codable {
    let projectGetResult: Bool?
    let projectGetProjects: [ProjectGetProject]?
}

// MARK: - ProjectGetProject
struct ProjectGetProject: Codable {
    let id, name, status, category: String?
    let type, updated: String?
    let value, units: Int?
    let address: Address?
    let contacts: Contacts?
}

// MARK: - Address
struct Address: Codable {
    let erf, street, street2, town: String?
    let city, region, postalCode: String?
}

// MARK: - Contacts
struct Contacts: Codable {
    let professional, contractor: [Contractor]?
}

// MARK: - Contractor
struct Contractor: Codable {
    let id, name, company, phone: String?
    let mobile, email, type: String?
}
```

```
  print(JSONString)
  let jsonData = JSONString.data(using: .utf8)!
  do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let tableData = try decoder.decode(GETprojects.self, from: jsonData)
    print(tableData)
      print("Rows in array: \(tableData.projectGetProjects?.count)")
  }
  catch {
    print (error)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let projectGetResult: Bool
    let projectGetProjects: [ProjectGetProject]
}

struct ProjectGetProject: Codable {
    let id, name, status, category: String
    let type, updated: String
    let value, units: Int
    let address: Address
    let contacts: Contacts
}

struct Address: Codable {
    let erf, street, street2, town: String
    let city, region, postalCode: String
}

struct Contacts: Codable {
    let professional, contractor: [Contractor]
}

struct Contractor: Codable {
    let id, name, company, phone: String
    let mobile, email, type: String
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let stringThing = """
    {
        "projectGetResult": true,
        "projectGetProjects": [
          {
              "id": "123-uni-que",
              "name": "Amazon",
              "status": "Planning",
              "category": "Commercial",
              "type": "Office Block",
              "updated": "21 March 2023",
              "value": 100000000,
              "units": 1,
              "address": {
                  "erf": "101-RE",
                  "street": "First Avenue",
                  "street2": "",
                  "town": "Cape Town",
                  "city": "Cape Town",
                  "region": "Western Cape",
                  "postalCode": "111"
              },
              "contacts": {
                  "professional": [
                      {
                      "id": "pr123",
                      "name":"Charles Darwin",
                      "company":"Darwin Designs",
                      "phone":"011 234 5678",
                      "mobile":"071 234 5678",
                      "email":"darwin@archi.com",
                      "type":"Architect"
                      },
                      {
                      "id": "pr234",
                      "name":"Bill Hutchins",
                      "company":"Hutchins Engineering",
                      "phone":"012 345 6789",
                      "mobile":"072 345 6789",
                      "email":"bill@engi.com",
                      "type":"Engineer"
                      },
        {
        "id": "pr345",
        "name":"Kevin Counter",
        "company":"KCQS",
        "phone":"013 456 7890",
        "mobile":"073 456 7890",
        "email":"k@county.com",
        "type":"Quantity Surveyor"
        }
        ],
        "contractor": [
        {
        "id": "con123",
        "name":"Leonardo da Vinci",
        "company":"MegaBuild",
        "phone":"014 567 8901",
        "mobile":"074 567 8901",
        "email":"leo@buildy.com",
        "type":"Main"
        },
        {
        "id": "con234",
        "name":"Steve Cleer",
                      "company":"SC Civils",
                      "phone":"015 678 9012",
                      "mobile":"075 678 9012",
                      "email":"sc@earthy.com",
                      "type":"Civil"
                      },
                      {
                          "id": "con345",
                          "name":"Warren Fright",
                          "company":"Electrified",
                          "phone":"016 789 0123",
                          "mobile":"076 789 0123",
                          "email":"@sparky.com",
                          "type":"Electrical"
                          }
                  ]
              }
          },
          {
              "id": "234-uni-que",
              "name": "TBC SA",
              "status": "On Site",
              "category": "Commercial",
              "type": "Office Block",
              "updated": "21 March 2023",
              "value": 200000000,
              "units": 2,
              "address": {
                  "erf": "102-RE",
                  "street": "Second Avenue",
                  "street2": "Corner of 4th",
                  "town": "Stellenbosch",
                  "city": "Cape Town",
                  "region": "Western Cape",
                  "postalCode": "222"
              },
              "contacts":  {
                      "professional": [
                          {
                          "id": "pr123",
                          "name":"Charles Darwin",
                          "company":"Darwin Designs",
                          "phone":"011 234 5678",
                          "mobile":"071 234 5678",
                          "email":"darwin@archi.com",
                          "type":"Architect"
                          },
                          {
                          "id": "pr234",
                          "name":"Bill Hutchins",
                          "company":"Hutchins Engineering",
                          "phone":"012 345 6789",
                          "mobile":"072 345 6789",
                          "email":"bill@engi.com",
                          "type":"Engineer"
                          },
                          {
                              "id": "pr345",
                              "name":"Kevin Counter",
                              "company":"KCQS",
                              "phone":"013 456 7890",
                              "mobile":"073 456 7890",
                              "email":"k@county.com",
                              "type":"Quantity Surveyor"
                              }
                      ],
                      "contractor": [
                          {
                          "id": "con123",
                          "name":"Leonardo da Vinci",
                          "company":"MegaBuild",
                          "phone":"014 567 8901",
                          "mobile":"074 567 8901",
                          "email":"leo@buildy.com",
                          "type":"Main"
                          },
                          {
                          "id": "con234",
                          "name":"Steve Cleer",
                          "company":"SC Civils",
                          "phone":"015 678 9012",
                          "mobile":"075 678 9012",
                          "email":"sc@earthy.com",
                          "type":"Civil"
                          },
                          {
                              "id": "con345",
                              "name":"Warren Fright",
                              "company":"Electrified",
                              "phone":"016 789 0123",
                              "mobile":"076 789 0123",
                              "email":"@sparky.com",
                              "type":"Electrical"
                              }
                      ]
                  }
          },
          {
              "id": "345-uni-que",
              "name": "Rolling Stock",
              "status": "Out to Tender",
              "category": "Commercial",
              "type": "Office Block",
              "updated": "21 March 2023",
              "value": 300000000,
              "units": 3,
              "address": {
                  "erf": "103-RE",
                  "street": "Third Avenue",
                  "street2": "",
                  "town": "Swellendam",
                  "city": "Drakenstein",
                  "region": "Western Cape",
                  "postalCode": "333"
              },
              "contacts":  {
                      "professional": [
                          {
                          "id": "pr123",
                          "name":"Charles Darwin",
                          "company":"Darwin Designs",
                          "phone":"011 234 5678",
                          "mobile":"071 234 5678",
                          "email":"darwin@archi.com",
                          "type":"Architect"
                          },
                          {
                          "id": "pr234",
                          "name":"Bill Hutchins",
                          "company":"Hutchins Engineering",
                          "phone":"012 345 6789",
                          "mobile":"072 345 6789",
                          "email":"bill@engi.com",
                          "type":"Engineer"
                          },
        {
        "id": "pr345",
        "name":"Kevin Counter",
        "company":"KCQS",
        "phone":"013 456 7890",
        "mobile":"073 456 7890",
        "email":"k@county.com",
        "type":"Quantity Surveyor"
        }
        ],
        "contractor": [
        {
        "id": "con123",
        "name":"Leonardo da Vinci",
        "company":"MegaBuild",
        "phone":"014 567 8901",
        "mobile":"074 567 8901",
        "email":"leo@buildy.com",
        "type":"Main"
        },
        {
        "id": "con234",
        "name":"Steve Cleer",
        "company":"SC Civils",
        "phone":"015 678 9012",
        "mobile":"075 678 9012",
        "email":"sc@earthy.com",
        "type":"Civil"
        },
        {
        "id": "con345",
        "name":"Warren Fright",
        "company":"Electrified",
        "phone":"016 789 0123",
        "mobile":"076 789 0123",
        "email":"@sparky.com",
        "type":"Electrical"
        }
        ]
        }}]}
    """
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        do{
            let jsonData = stringThing.data(using: .utf8)!
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
            print(result)
        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```